# Referencing specific values from returned JSON data via API

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api

I have created an API call for the "Transport for London" unified API. My code works just fine and is successfully displaying the data within my html document. However, I'm struggling to access a certain specific variable within the returned JSON that I would like to also display.

The variable I value I would like to access is "StatusSeverityDescription".

Below is the success functionality from my Ajax call, please note this works:

```
success: function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(key,value) {
                        var line = value.name;

                       //append list item to div with id of Data
                        $("#Data").append("<li>"+line+"</li>"+"<br>");
                        });
```

Returned JSON:

```
{
"$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
"id": "bakerloo",
"name": "Bakerloo",
"modeName": "tube",
"disruptions": [

],
"created": "2017-01-10T17:28:11.04Z",
"modified": "2017-01-10T17:28:11.04Z",
"lineStatuses": [
  {
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineStatus, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "id": 0,
    "statusSeverity": 10,
    "statusSeverityDescription": "Good Service",
    "created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "validityPeriods": [

    ]
  }
],
"routeSections": [

],
"serviceTypes": [
  {
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "name": "Regular",
    "uri": "/Line/Route?ids=Bakerloo&serviceTypes=Regular"
  }
]
```

},

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Have you tried accessing the properties of the response object? Indexing into those that are arrays?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read anything on how to use objects/arrays in JS? Any basic tutorials will cover this.

Comment: Hi Jon, yes I have read/studied this subject. In this case I just didn't identify one of the arrays within the returned JSON. Turned out to be a simple solution:    var status = value.lineStatuses[0].statusSeverityDescription;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lineStatuses` is an array inside `data`. You are interested in its first element:

```
data.lineStatuses[0].statusSeverityDescription
```

More generally:

```
for (var index in data.lineStatuses) {
    //Do something with data.lineStatuses[index].statusSeverityDescription
}
```

Comment: Thanks you Lajos, this is exactly what I needed.